# Flashing without a firmware

Tags: rom-flashing, device-firmware

I received a second handed tablet recently, but it came with a custom formware that had some problems.

I proceeded to remove it and flashed the stock one but came across two problems. If I try with adb sideload it's telling me that the signature failed and won't install.

If i try with the .zip file it says Failed to mount "/aboot" and won't install it.
I tried with different firmwares for all the different versions of the model but without success

The tablet is a Mediacom SmartPad i10 3G, sadly I don't have access to further informations about it since I can't boot. Also, the tablet won't recharge and actually lose battery when plugged even if it was turned off before plugging it and now is at 2%.

How do I fix this situation?

Comment: return it to seller

Comment: https://androidmtk.com/flash-stock-rom-using-intel-phone-flash-tool Disclaimer: Do not try to flash with low battery. Flash at own risk. https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3679519